# Is there any way to shorten this code in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an assignment which tells me to create a file where you insert random alphanumeric chars and the keyword "VIRUS" into the file. I think the logic I used was enough for this assignment.

I am just wondering is there any way for me to shorten the code I wrote? because I want to learn more on how to efficiently write code. I'm still a noob and self-taught; constructive feedback is welcome. Here is my assignment. Thanks! :D

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace RBC_Task_3 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            beginning: Console.WriteLine(
                "This program inputs a random alphanumeric array into a file.\n" +
                "The keyword \"VIRUS\" is sometimes inserted randomly inside the file.\n"
            );
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
            string folderName = @"c:\Top Folder";
            string path1 = Path.Combine(folderName, "File Folder");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path1);
            if (Directory.Exists(path1)) {
                for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                    string fileName = "file" + i + ".dat";
                    string filePath = Path.Combine(path1, fileName);
                    File.Create(filePath).Dispose();
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.Write("Press Y/y if you want to begin  ");
            string c = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Clear();
            var rC = new Random();
            int sP = 0;
            if (c == "Y" || c == "y") {
                sP = rC.Next(1, 4);
                if (sP == 1) {
                    goto sequenceOne;
                } else if (sP == 2) {
                    goto sequenceTwo;
                } else {
                    goto sequenceThree;
                }
            } else {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    "Press Y/y if you want to begin.\nPress any key to continue"
                );
                Console.ReadKey();
                Console.Clear();
                goto beginning;
            }
            sequenceOne: var stringChars = new char[26];
            var random = new Random();
            var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++) {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
            }
            string string1 = new string(stringChars);
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Top Folder\File Folder\file1.dat",
                string1);
            using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@
                "C:\Top Folder\File Folder\file1.dat")) {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine("file1.dat is a clean file");
                    Console.WriteLine("Path to file1.dat - {0}", path1);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                goto end;
            }
            sequenceTwo: var stringChars2 = new char[26];
            var random2 = new Random();
            var chars2 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZxxxxx";
            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars2.Length; i++) {
                stringChars2[i] = chars2[random2.Next(chars2.Length)];
            }
            string string2 = new string(stringChars2);
            string2 = string2.Replace("x", "\"VIRUS\"");
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Top Folder\File Folder\file2.dat",
                string2);
            using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@
                "C:\Top Folder\FIle Folder\file2.dat")) {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "file2.dat is a HIGH THREAT virus file");
                    Console.WriteLine("Path to file2.dat - {0}\n",
                        path1);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                goto end;
            }
            sequenceThree: var stringChars3 = new char[26];
            var random3 = new Random();
            var chars3 = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZx";
            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars3.Length; i++) {
                stringChars3[i] = chars3[random3.Next(chars3.Length)];
            }
            string string3 = new string(stringChars3);
            string3 = string3.Replace("x", "\"VIRUS\"");
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Top Folder\File Folder\file3.dat",
                string3);
            using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@
                "C:\Top Folder\File Folder\file3.dat")) {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        "file3.dat is a MODERATE THREAT virus file"
                    );
                    Console.WriteLine("Path to file3.dat - {0}\n",
                        path1);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadKey();
                goto end;
            }
            end: Console.WriteLine("\nDo you want to try again?Y/N");
            string end = Console.ReadLine();
            if (end == "Y" || end == "y") {
                Console.Clear();
                goto beginning;
            } else {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Goodbye...Press any key to exit");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please pay more attention to the formatting of your post. There's a preview available when you post - surely this isn't how you *want* the question to look... and do you *really* have 3 or 4 blank lines between each line of code? I strongly suspect you don't. Copy and paste your code straight out of Visual Studio, highlight it all and press Ctrl-K and it will be *much* easier for people to help you.

Comment: Learn to format your code. Put 4 spaces then your code on each line. This will make the formatting nice. Don't expect any answers if you keep the question like that.

Comment: Your liberal use of `goto` makes the logic a bit hard to follow, not to mention refactor.

Comment: Instead of using goto, you should split your code into separate short methods. Make a method for each logical step and especially for any repeating steps which may differ in parameter values only. Once you have done that, you can optimize these short methods more easily.

Comment: This question should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about the formatting guys as this was my very first post. I didn't know about the correct formatting when I posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code can be since just copy and pasted and that should **never** be your first thought of what to do, for example, this is all your doing to generate a string so you can just call this code in each of your sequences.

```
private string GenerateString(int idx)
{
    var stringChars = new char[26];
    var random = new Random();
    var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++) {
        stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next(chars.Length)];
    }
    return new string(stringChars);
}
//Example call (for sequence one) = string1 = GenerateString(1);
```

---

Writing to the file is similar

```
private void WriteFile(int idx, string inputString ,string threatLevel)
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Top Folder\File Folder\file2.dat", inputString);
    string filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\Top Folder\FIle Folder", 
                                     string.Format("file{0}.dat", idx));
    using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(filePath))
    {
        string s = "";
        while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.WriteLine("file{0}.dat is a {1} file", idx, threatLevel);
            Console.WriteLine("Path to file{0}.dat - {1}\n", idx, filePath);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
//WriteToFile(1, string1, "clean");
//WriteToFile(2, string2, "HIGH THREAT virus");
//WriteToFile(3, string2, "MODERATE THREAT virus");
```

You should look up switch statements and figure out a way to get rid of the goto statements also.

Comment: I didn't copy paste anyone's code, thank you for the help! I will study on what you said.. I knew what I wrote was very long; sole reason why I came here :D

Comment: @Airynd - It looks to me like you copy and pasted your own code, 3 times... And no worries, goto is a very old keyword that has since replaced by better ways of doing things (this is debatable but I stand firmly on the side of never use this keyword)